# Random Forest Classifier :To which class corresponds the probabilities

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest, data-science

I am using the `RandomForestClassifier` from `pyspark.ml.classification`

I run the model on a binary class dataset and display the probabilities.

I have the following in the col probabilities :

```
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------+
|label|prediction|probability                            |
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------+
|0.0  |0.0       |[0.9005918461098429,0.0994081538901571]|
|1.0  |1.0       |[0.6051335859900139,0.3948664140099861]|
+-----+----------+---------------------------------------+
```

I have a list of 2 elements which obviously correspond to the probabilities of the predicted class.

***My question*** : probability[0 corresponds always to the value of prediction whereas in the spark documentation it is not clear!

Comment: I agree, the documentation is not clear +1.

Comment: I will observe that the sum of the two numbers in each probability tuple is 1.  My guess is that, for example for `0.0`, that 90% of the time the model got it right, and 10% of the time it got it wrong.

Comment: Probabilities correspond  to consecutive labels so if you see the second row in practice it is a bug. In that case a [mcve] and / or JIRA ticket would be welcome.

Comment: @user6910411 You mean that Probability[0] is always for one class and Probabiity[1] is for the other class. how to tell which probability is for which class and second question why is row2 is a bug. Thank you!

Comment: It is `[P(label=i) for i in 0..#labels]` and doesn't depend on the prediction. The case you have is possible only if you use non standard thresholds (with preference to label=1). Or it is a bug. One way or another question is not useful without MCVE.

Comment: many thanks @ user6910411

Comment: @moufkir: hi, did you get your answer...?  I did not understand answers given on that questions.... If you did get it, please can you explain it to me? Is it always "first probability = probability of class "0" and second = probability of class "1"" (because 0<1)...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as asking: does the first element in the array under the column 'predictions' always correspond to the "predicted class", by which you mean the label the Random Forest Classifier predicted the observation should have.

If I have that correct, the answer is Yes.

The items in the arrays in both `probability` rows can be read as the model telling you:

[`'My confidence that the predicted label = the true label', 
'My confidence that the label != the true label']`

In the case of multiple labels being predicted, then you would have the model telling you:

[`'My confidence that the label I predict  = specific label 1', 
'My confidence that the label I predict = specific label 2', 
...'My confidence that the label I predict = specific label N']`

This is indexed by the N labels you are trying to predict (which means you have to be careful about the way the labels are structured).

Perhaps it would help to take a look at [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9424/spark-mllib-multiclass-logistic-regression-how-to-get-the-probabilities-of-all?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). You could do something like:

`model = pipeline.fit(trainig_data)
predictions = model.transform(test_data)
print predictions.show(10)`

(Using the relevant pipeline and data from your examples.)

This will show you the probabilities for each class.

Comment: Thank you @Savage Henry s in my case I have only 2 classes 0 and 1 and I am interested to have only the probability of always predicting 1. so as the array of probabilities contains only 2 elements I took always probability[1] referring to @ user6910411 answer. is that correct ? and anyway when we are in apply mode there is no True label. the documentation is not clear about this!

Comment: My apologies, but I'm not following your question. Maybe this will help: the way to read the entries in the table you posted is (going column by column): the true label is 0 | model predicted 0 | [Probability assigned to 0 being the right label], [1-Probability assigned to 0 being the right label, AKA the Probability assigned to 1 being the right label]. The first element is relative to the predicted value; it will, given no tweaks to other parameters, generally always be >0.50.

Comment: Thank you @Savage Henry for taking time going through the steps it clarifies a lot. so let imagine that now I have my Model already built and try to apply it on a new data set for which we do not have the label (0 or 1). The model will generate a prediction of a class (0 or 1) so if I am interested in the probability of 1 I have to go through this like that (if the prediction is 0 then I have to take probability[1] if the prediction = 1 I have to get the probability[0]. Am I right?

Comment: This depends a lot on your modeling framework. The standard practice for predicting a binary outcome is to make the target values something like 0 and 1 (or maybe 1 and 2) so that they are numeric. Some packages can handle categorical data (A or B), but under the hood they're doing the conversion. But the output would again be something like: | True label is A | Model predicts label is A | [Probability assigned to label being A], [Probability assigned to label being B] |

Comment: Thank you @Savage Henry, Yes I  have already converted the label to 0 for False and 1 for True. just as I have in the column probability an array of 2 values so I consider that probability[0] being the probability of False and probability[1] as the probability of True. As  the documentation of apache is not very explicit : "probabilityCol Vector "probability" Vector of length # classes equal to rawPrediction normalized to a multinomial distribution Classification only"  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html

Answer (score 0):

I post almost the same question here and I think the answer might help you:
[Scala: how to know which probability correspond to which class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57142056/scala-how-to-know-which-probability-correspond-to-which-class/57481197#57481197)

The answer is before the fit of the model.

To fit the model we use a labelIndexer on the target. This label indexer transform the target into an indexe by descending frequency.

ex: if, in my target I have 20% of "aa" and 80% of "bb" label indexer will create a column "label" that took the value 0 for "bb" and 1 for "aa" (because I "bb" is ore frequent than "aa")

When we fit a random forest, the probabilities correspond to the order of frequency.

In binary classification:

- first proba = probability that the class is the most frequent class in the train set
- second proba = probability that the class is the less frequent class in the train set

Comment: if you are lucky enought to have a version of spark greater or equal to "2.3.0" you can use "setStringOrderType" to choose other way than descending frequency to create your indexe (ex: alphabetical order)

Comment: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/StringIndexer.scala